# How to write a flask script to split strings and reassemble them into a hyperlink?

Tags: html, flask, frontend

I need to split *mystring* (looks like this: "SomeText,www.abc.com") and reassemble them into a hyperlink.

```
<td class="pmid">
    <% var parts = h.mystring.split(",");%>
    <a href="{{ parts[1] }}">{{ parts[0] }}</a>
</td>
```

I've been getting warnings saying that *parts* is not defined. What am I doing wrong?